# Out of the sudden (after an Android SDK Manager packages update) an Apache import stopped resolving

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was using Android Studio, I opened the SDK Manager and downloaded some new updates and APIS.

Then I closed it.

I opened Eclipse (another older project there) and out of the sudden my project wouldnt compile anymore:

```
The import org.apache.http.util cannot be resolved
```

The developer who had worked on that project before was using a class from that package - EncodingUtils in the following way:

```
String postData = "token=" + token + "&url=" + URL;
    webView.postUrl(Api.getAppLoginUrl(),
            EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
```

Why would this package import stop resolving out of nowhere?
What could I replace this EncodingUtils.getBytes method with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, when I hovered over EncodingUtils (cannot be resolved), one of the suggestions was Fix Project Setup where I was taken to a window that offered to add android.jar to project setup, so I did and the problem disappeared!